# How to use gorutines in a cycle for filling of struct?

Tags: go

There are such models:

```
type ChromeBasedDirections struct {
    CurrencyFromName string
    CurrencyToName   string
    URL              string
    ParseResponse    ParseResponse
}

type ParseResponse struct {
    CurrentPrice float64
    Change24H    float64
    Err          error
}

type ParseResponseChan struct {
    URL          string
    CurrentPrice float64
    Change24H    float64
    Err          error
}
```

The function  is like this:

```
func ParseBNCByURL(u string, chanResponse chan models.ParseResponseChan) {
    var parseResponse models.ParseResponseChan
    //..
    // code that fill up parseResponse
    //..
    if err != nil {
        parseResponse.Err = err
        chanResponse <- parseResponse
        return

    }
    parseResponse.CurrentPrice = price
    parseResponse.Change24H = change24H
    chanResponse <- parseResponse
    return
}
```

And this is how the function call goes:

```
func initParserMultiTread() {
    var urls = []string{"url_0","url_1","url_2","url_n"} // on production it will be taken from the json file
    var chromeBasedDirections []models.ChromeBasedDirections
    for _, url := range urls {
        chromeBasedDirections = append(chromeBasedDirections, models.ChromeBasedDirections{
            CurrencyFromName: "",
            CurrencyToName:   "",
            URL:              url,
            ParseResponse:    models.ParseResponse{},
        })
    }
    var parseResponseChan = make(chan models.ParseResponseChan) // here's how to do without hardcode?
    for _, dir := range chromeBasedDirections {
        go controllers.ParseBNCByURL(dir.URL, parseResponseChan)
    }
}
```

If `initParserMultiTread` is executed, the function will complete before `ParseBNCByURL` is executed. This is because the channel has not been read. If it was possible to use hardcode, then it would be possible for each url_n to create its own chan `models.ParseResponseChan` and then in a loop compare `ChromeBasedDirections.URL` and `ParseResponseChan.URL`, and if there is a match then fill in `ChromeBasedDirections.ParseResponse`.

But I need to avoid hardcode and do everything in a loop. In general, this is far from the first option as I try to do multi-threaded execution of the `ParseBNCByURL` function.

That is, there is a `ChromeBasedDirections` model with filled `CurrencyFrom/ToName` and `URL` fields, and I need to execute `ParseBNCByURL` in a multi-thread, which will fill `ParseResponse`.

I tried it again, but the function doesn't work in multithreaded mode:

```
var urls = []string{"url_0","url_1","url_2","url_n"} 
var chromeResults []models.ChromeBasedDirections
for _, url := range urls {
    var chromeResult = make(chan models.ChromeBasedDirections)
    go controllers.ParseBNCByURL(url, chromeResult)
    chromeResults = append(chromeResults, <-chromeResult)
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Get and process the data for each URL in separate goroutines and send the results to one place in your `initParserMultiTread ` method to process them?

Comment: @eminlala Yes, in the `initParserMultiTread` function I get the Url from a json file, or I immediately have 'chromeBasedDirections` with `CurrencyFrom/ToName` and `URL` filled in, then I call the `ParseBNCByURL` function and pass the URL as an argument. The `ParseBNCByURL` function should fill in 'ParseResponse' and return (write to the channel) `ParseResponse`. And then from the channel I have to fill in `[]models.ChromeBasedDirections`. The `ParseBNCByURL` function must be executed in a multi-thread. It is not known in advance how many URLs will be used for parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are not reading the `parseResponseChan` anywhere. All your goroutines get blocked because of that, and that is why the `initParserMultiTread` function finishes before your goroutines.

You need to add code for reading the `parseResponseChan` channel, as well as code for closing the `parseResponseChan` channel once all goroutines are done with execution.

One solution is synchronization with `sync.WaitGroup`.

First a change in your `ParseBNCByURL` function. This function needs to send a signal when it's done.

```
func ParseBNCByURL( wg *sync.WaitGroup, u string, chanResponse chan models.ParseResponseChan) {
    defer wg.Done() //this signals when the goroutine is done
    
//the rest of the function's body
```

In the `initParserMultiTread` function, you need a way to wait for signals from all goroutines to close the `parseResponseChan` channel and to read the response from that channel.

```
func initParserMultiTread() {
    var urls = []string{"url_0","url_1","url_2","url_n"} // on production it will be taken from the json file
    var chromeBasedDirections []models.ChromeBasedDirections
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(urls)) // add how many goroutines will be initialized
    for _, url := range urls {
            chromeBasedDirections = append(chromeBasedDirections, models.ChromeBasedDirections{
                    CurrencyFromName: "",
                    CurrencyToName:   "",
                    URL:              url,
                    ParseResponse:    models.ParseResponse{},
            })
    }

    var parseResponseChan = make(chan models.ParseResponseChan)

        //init a goroutine for closing the parseResponseChan once all goroutines are done
        go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan models.ParseResponseChan) {
            wg.Wait() //wait for all goroutines to send the signal
            close(ch) //close the channel
        }(&wg, parseResponseChan)

    for _, dir := range chromeBasedDirections {
            go controllers.ParseBNCByURL(&wg, dir.URL, parseResponseChan)
    }

    //read the responses from the channel
    for response := range parseResponseChan {
        //some code to handle the responses
    }
}
```

Once all the goroutines are initialized, you start reading from the `parseResponseChan` channel. This will block the `initParserMultiTread` function from returning until all goroutines are done with execution and the `parseResponseChan` channel closes.